# Discrepancy between `apt-get upgrade` and update manager

Tags: upgrade, apt, updates, package-management, update-manager

I use Ubuntu 12.04.2 and I've just finished running `apt-get update`. According to `apt-get upgrade`,  there are 5 packages to be upgraded, in a total of 1533 kB; while the update manager indicates there are 52,8 MB in 13 pacakges.

Why the discrepancy? (also, why `apt-get upgrade` says 4 packages won't be upgraded?)

### output of `apt-get upgrade`

```
ruda@machine:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Os pacotes a seguir serão mantidos em suas versões atuais:
  libminiupnpc8 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
Os pacotes a seguir serão atualizados:
  dbus dbus-x11 libdbus-1-3 libdbus-1-3:i386 linux-libc-dev
5 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 4 não atualizados.
É preciso baixar 1.533 kB de arquivos.
Depois desta operação, 7.168 B adicionais de espaço em disco serão usados.
```

### packages marked by update manager

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

### output of `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade --simulate`

```
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Calculando atualização... Pronto
Os NOVOS pacotes a seguir serão instalados:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-48 linux-headers-3.2.0-48-generic linux-image-3.2.0-48-generic minissdpd
Os pacotes a seguir serão atualizados:
  dbus dbus-x11 libdbus-1-3 libdbus-1-3:i386 libminiupnpc8 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev
9 pacotes atualizados, 4 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 0 não atualizados.
Inst libdbus-1-3 [1.4.18-1ubuntu1.3] (1.4.18-1ubuntu1.4 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64]) [libdbus-1-3:amd64 on libdbus-1-3:i386] [libdbus-1-3:i386 on libdbus-1-3:amd64] [libdbus-1-3:i386 ]
Inst libdbus-1-3:i386 [1.4.18-1ubuntu1.3] (1.4.18-1ubuntu1.4 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [i386])
Conf libdbus-1-3 (1.4.18-1ubuntu1.4 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Conf libdbus-1-3:i386 (1.4.18-1ubuntu1.4 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [i386])
Inst linux-image-3.2.0-48-generic (3.2.0-48.74 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Inst dbus [1.4.18-1ubuntu1.3] (1.4.18-1ubuntu1.4 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Inst dbus-x11 [1.4.18-1ubuntu1.3] (1.4.18-1ubuntu1.4 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Inst libminiupnpc8 [1.6-3ubuntu1] (1.6-precise2 Bitcoin - Stable Channel:12.04/precise [amd64])
Inst linux-generic [3.2.0.45.54] (3.2.0.48.58 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64]) []
Inst linux-image-generic [3.2.0.45.54] (3.2.0.48.58 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64]) []
Inst linux-headers-3.2.0-48 (3.2.0-48.74 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [all]) []
Inst linux-headers-3.2.0-48-generic (3.2.0-48.74 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64]) []
Inst linux-headers-generic [3.2.0.45.54] (3.2.0.48.58 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Inst linux-libc-dev [3.2.0-45.70] (3.2.0-48.74 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Inst minissdpd (1.1.20111007-3 Ubuntu:12.04/precise [amd64])
Conf linux-image-3.2.0-48-generic (3.2.0-48.74 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Conf dbus (1.4.18-1ubuntu1.4 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Conf dbus-x11 (1.4.18-1ubuntu1.4 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Conf libminiupnpc8 (1.6-precise2 Bitcoin - Stable Channel:12.04/precise [amd64])
Conf linux-image-generic (3.2.0.48.58 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Conf linux-headers-3.2.0-48 (3.2.0-48.74 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [all])
Conf linux-headers-3.2.0-48-generic (3.2.0-48.74 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Conf linux-headers-generic (3.2.0.48.58 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Conf linux-generic (3.2.0.48.58 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Conf linux-libc-dev (3.2.0-48.74 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Conf minissdpd (1.1.20111007-3 Ubuntu:12.04/precise [amd64])
```

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` refuses to install or remove stuff for changes in dependencies. `apt-get dist-upgrade` has no such qualms.

Comment: @strugee Yes, that would explain the 4 packages that `apt-get` won't upgrade. But (5+4) = 9, what about the four others?

Comment: What is the exact output of `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade --simulate`?

Comment: @gertvdijk Updated my question with this info

Comment: I don't see any difference. *"9 pacotes atualizados, 4 pacotes novos instalados"* means 13 updates, just as with the GUI tool.